# I am required to implement the specialization of template function which performs the functionality of finding smaller of two C-style strings

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, googletest, template-specialization

I had written this code to implement template specialisation for the above problem but the code is not correct because it is returning value from the template function that i had written at the top without checking the actual template specialised function that i had written below it for finding
smaller of two C-style strings.All test cases are passed whether they are right or wrong.Please help me solve this problem.
Here is my code

code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T smaller(T a, T b) {
    if (a < b)
        return a;
    return b;
}
//template<typename T>
//T smaller(T a, T b, T c)
//{
//  if (a < b && a < c)
//      return a;
//  else if (b < c && b < a)
//      return b;
//  else if (c < a && c < b)
//      return c;
//  
//}
template <>
const char* smaller<const char *>(const char *a,const char *b)
{
    //int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
    if (strcmp(a, b) == 0)
        return "0";
    else if (strcmp(a, b) > 0)
        return b;
    else if (strcmp(a, b) < 0)
        return a;
    
}
//TEST(smaller, TestName) {
//  EXPECT_EQ('B', smaller('a','B'));
//  EXPECT_EQ(12, smaller(15, 12));
//  EXPECT_EQ(33.1, smaller(33.1, 44.2));
//  //EXPECT_TRUE(true);
//}

//TEST(smaller, TestName_2) {
//  EXPECT_EQ('B', smaller('a', 'B','c'));
//  EXPECT_EQ(12, smaller(15, 12,13));
//  EXPECT_EQ(33.1, smaller(33.1, 44.2,44.5));
//  //EXPECT_TRUE(true);
//}

TEST(smaller, TestName_3) {
    string a = "ABC";
    string b = "DEF";
    EXPECT_EQ("ABC", smaller(a, b));
    string c = "AB";
    string d = "DE";
    EXPECT_EQ("AB", smaller(c, d));
    string e = "Ba";
    string f = "Dd";
    EXPECT_EQ("Ba", smaller(e, f));
}
```

Comment: Hey, see `EXPECT_EQ("ABC", smaller(a, b));` as an example, you passed a and b, which are all of `std::string` type. maybe you should just implement the `std::string` version specialisation.

Comment: Hi @SHP , Now i know that those test cases that i had created were wrong. There were issues with the type of parameters that i had passed and my code as well.Moreover, i want to mention that the requirements are the same that i had mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement it like what you did before

Since I have no idea what `TEST` is, I have changed it in an other version.

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T smaller(T a, T b) {
  if (a < b) return a;
  return b;
}

template <>
const char *smaller<const char *>(const char *a, const char *b) {
  int ans = strcmp(a, b);
  if (ans == 0) {
    return "0";
  }
  return ans > 0 ? b : a;
}

template <typename T>
void EXPECT_EQ(T ans, T give) {
  assert(ans == give);
}

template <>
void EXPECT_EQ(const char *ans, const char *give) {
  assert(!strcmp(ans, give));
}

int main() {
  const char *a = "ABC";
  const char *b = "DEF";
  EXPECT_EQ("ABC", smaller(a, b));
  const char *c = "AB";
  const char *d = "DE";
  EXPECT_EQ("AB", smaller(c, d));
  const char *e = "Ba";
  const char *f = "Dd";
  EXPECT_EQ("Ba", smaller(e, f));
}
```

Comment: I had made some changes in it and it works .Thank you so much @SHP

Answer (score 0):

```
it works for me. 

#include"pch.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T smaller(T a, T b) {
    if (a < b) return a;
    return b;
}

template <>
const char* smaller<const char*>(const char* a, const char* b) {
    int ans = strcmp(a, b);
    if (ans == 0) {
        return "0";
    }
    return ans > 0 ? b : a;
}

//template <typename T>
//void EXPECT_EQ(T ans, T give) {
//    assert(ans == give);
//}
//
//template <>
//void EXPECT_EQ(const char* ans, const char* give) {
//    assert(!strcmp(ans, give));
//}

TEST(smaller, TestName_3) {
    const char* a = "ABC";
    const char* b = "DEF";
    const char* aa = smaller(a, b);
    EXPECT_EQ(a, aa);
    const char* c = "AB";
    const char* d = "DE";
    const char* dd = smaller(c, d);
    EXPECT_EQ(c, dd);
    const char* e = "Ba";
    const char* f = "Dd";
    const char* ff = smaller(e, f);
    EXPECT_EQ(e, ff);
}
```